# Why do I get stack overflow BEFORE all the possible combinations have been reached?

Tags: vb.net, save, stack-overflow, brute-force

So.
I am making a bruteforcer in visual basic.
It has a charset as shown below:

```
Dim charset as string
charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890."
```

There is 37 different chars right? The program is made to search for all the different combinations  made with this charset, with a maximum of 3 different letters. For example

This is a combination that can be made: *ac6*

So since there is 37 letters and 3 slots the possible combinations are 37^3

But I wanted my program not to try the same combination twice.

So it saves every single combination tried in this location (Desktop)

```
Dim filex As System.IO.StreamWriter
            filex = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\desktop\alreadytested.txt", True)
            filex.WriteLine(combination)
            filex.Close()
```

And, at the start of the Sub that checks for new combinations, I have this

```
text = File.ReadAllText("c:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\desktop\alreadytested.txt")
index = text.IndexOf(combination) 'checks if it has been generated already
   If index >= 0 Then
       keyword() 'The sub
   End If
```

But after some combinations (in this case the max 37^3 ~= 50.000 and I the program tried around 5200 times) I get this error

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*

And this error points in this line of code

```
filex = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\desktop\alreadytested.txt", True)
```

But why? at 5200 there is still 44800 possible random combinations, why do I get an overflow?

**It would make sense if I got it when I had 50000 combinations out of 50000 possible tested, but now I have 10% only, so why do I get an overflow?**

Comment: There's lack of code in the question. For example, how do you call this to begin with? You cannot infinitely use recursion on a method, so a while loop (maybe with a small delay?) would be better - one example of a fix.

Comment: The call stack only takes so many calls until it overflows, and each time you call a method its return address and possibly its arguments are added to the call stack.

Comment: In a console application, I call this from the sub main after setting some settings such as customizing the charset. So after  the settings are complete and set, it goes to Sub Keyword using keyword()

From there, it generates a new combination -> checks the file to see if the combination already exists -> if it does, it runs keyword() to go back to the start of the Sub -> if it doesnt it saves the newly generated combination in the file and goes back to the start using keyword() to get a different combination.

Thanks for your response, please tell me if you need any other data.

Comment: So due to that you keep calling `keyword()` from itself you are using too much recursion and thus getting the overflow. Use a while-loop instead (with or without delay) and you should no longer experience the problem.

Comment: For the record, whenever you want to start the loop from the beginning again AND stopping the rest from executing, call `Continue While`.

Comment: You open and close the file for each combination?

Comment: Did Do While (combination < mostAmountOfCombinations)-> Loop and it worked! Thanks for the help sir. Have a nice day, this question was solved :)

Comment: Glad to hear! I wrote it as an answer so this question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep on recursively calling the `keyword()` method. Every time you call a method its return address and possibly its arguments is/are added to the call stack. The callstack can only take a certain amount of calls before it overflows, and for your computer and that specific method of yours, that amount seems to be about 5200.

You should switch to using for example a `While`-loop instead, and whenever you want to block the rest of the execution and go back to the beginning of the loop you'd just call `Continue While`.

---

A little side note is also that you shouldn't open and close the file every time you read/write to it. Store the contents of the file in a long string (or even better, in a [**HashSet(Of T)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)) instead and check that every time you need to, then at the end of the loop you may write all the contents to a file.

If you still wish to write to the file during the process then do so. But instead open a stream before your loop which you keep writing to until the loop is finished, *then close the stream.*

Comment: Good suggestions. I would like to add that it may be worth to separate the work on several threads/tasks. Like split the combinations into chunks of 100 or 500 and handle them async.